# Difficulty installing Custom Raspbian on Raspberry Pi 2 [USING WINDOWS]

Tags: boot-issues

I am having a hard time installing [this OS](http://pd-la.info/pdpi/) onto my Raspberry Pi. Specifically, the Pi does not seem to boot (i.e. the red light and green light are both on).

I used [DD for Windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd) to put the OS on the microSD card. DISKPART and WinDD show me that the microSD has two partitions now: Partition 1, Primary, FAT, 56MB, and Partition 0, Primary, Linux Ext2, 7520MB. This seems to me sufficient proof that the image was written correctly (although, TBH, I don't know).

I also know that my Rpi2 works correctly with regular ol' Raspbian.

Anyway, I am baffled, and not sure what to try next. Looking forward to your insight.

Comment: Have you tried formatting your SD card before writing the OS? Formatting it with a tool like SD formatter will give the card back it's original storage capacity. Then the writing tool will create partitions.

Comment: Partition 0 or Partition 2? The FAT partition MUST be the first partition as it contains the bootcode (firmware) needed for the GPU and then the CPU to start up. Are you seeing anything on screen that points to an error? If so, can you add that to your question?

Comment: I haven't seen anything on screen that points to an error. Also, it is definitely partition 0. I guess that means that it isn't booting because the FAT partition has to be partition 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while using DD is something viable mostly on Linux, on Windows I'd recommand to use native tools that are known to work. 
You should use [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_ARM_Installer#Windows_Vista_.26_7)  or [HP](http://www.techspot.com/downloads/6582-hp-usb-disk-storage-format-tool.html) format tools.

More generally speaking simply follow [Adafruit tutorials](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-raspberry-pi-lesson-1-preparing-and-sd-card-for-your-raspberry-pi/making-an-sd-card-using-a-windows-vista-slash-7) would make your life easier.

Comment: NOOBS may not be much help for the OP as the OS that they want to install only comes as a .iso (or possibly an .img) file and does not seem to be one of the available Distributions from the Foundation...

Comment: Indeed : better know what is going on while installing. Corrected